# How to change the order of values in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This might be simple or it might not be, I need to change the order of the displayed data from "DBG DBN POST PRE" to "PRE DBG DBN POST" both in the plot and the legend

Here is my code:

```
Actigraph %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = Standing:Sitting) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = Condition)) + 
     geom_boxplot()
```

and here is the output

[image]

EDIT**

```
dput(head(Actigraph))
structure(list(Participant.Code = c("AE1_25", "AE1_25", "AE1_25", 
"AE1_25", "AE1_25", "AE4_23"), Condition = c("DBG", "DBG", "DBG", 
"DBG", "DBG", "DBG"), Day.within.condition = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 1L), Standing = c(34L, 631L, 10517L, 8467L, 33L, 892L), Stepping = c(76L, 
598L, 788L, 598L, 59L, 234L), Cycling = c(220L, 56L, 4266L, 91L, 
2920L, 144L), Sitting = c(9392L, 23589L, 12144L, 17205L, 17396L, 
2550L), X = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.1 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), X.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), X.4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.5 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), X.6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.7 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X.8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Generally this sort of question is answered already. In this case the answer will be to change the order of the levels attribute of a factor variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `forcats::lvls_reorder()`, like this:

```
Actigraph %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = Standing:Sitting) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = name, y = value, fill = forcats::lvls_reorder(Condition, c(4,1:3)))) + 
  geom_boxplot() + labs(fill="Condition")
```